# Event binding and modifying innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, innerhtml

If i have bound events to several elements contained in, say, a table. If i regenerate this table's `innerHTML` by building a new string and assigning it, are the events still bound ? Do I have to rebind them all ?

Does `jQuery.delegate` also work if I modify the `innerHTML` manually ?

Comment: You could have tested this in as much time as it took to post the question. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i regenerate this table's innerHTML buy building a new string and assigning it, are the event still bound?

No.

> Do i have to rebind them all ?

Yes.

> Does jQuery.delegate also work if i modify the innerHTML manually ?

If you're modifying the `innerHTML` of the element on which `.delegate()` was called, no. If you're modifying the `innerHTML` of one of its children, yes.

Comment: Thanks ! I added another question to my post about jQuery.delegate().

Answer (score 1):

You will need to rebind them, but jquery `delegate` or new `on` will work if you bind on element that will always be in the DOM like body or document.

```
$('body').on('click', 'table td', function() {

});
```

Comment: By the way, is event delegation slow ? Because i have dynamic elements containing dynamic elements containing dynamic elements, etc. I might have to create things like 'body .Keyboard .Layout .Key' or even larger selectors for that. Would it slow down ?

Comment: @Virus721 I thought that delegate was deprecated in favor of on but it's not, and I don't think it will slow down anything, since all event bubble and on simple catch that event higher in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rebind for sure. When you regen the innerhtml it destroys the dom elements that were in it and any bindings they had.